# Passing field from extended user model to template in Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-templates

I am having an issue passing a field from an extended user model to a template in Django.

I defined the extended user fields in a model in a new app called user_management:

```
#user_management/models.py

from __future__ import unicode_literals
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class lab_user(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    personal_order_list_url = models.URLField("Personal order list URL", max_length=255, blank=False, unique=True)
    abbreviation_code = models.CharField("Abbreviation code", max_length=3, blank=False, unique=True)
    def save(self, force_insert=False, force_update=False):
        self.personal_order_list_url = self.personal_order_list_url.lower()
        self.abbreviation_code = self.abbreviation_code.upper()
        super(lab_user, self).save(force_insert, force_update)
```

I then registered the new fields in admin.py:

```
#user_management/admin.py
from __future__ import unicode_literals
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin as BaseUserAdmin
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

from .models import lab_user

class lab_user_inline(admin.StackedInline):
    model = lab_user
    can_delete = False
    verbose_name_plural = 'Additional Fields'

class UserAdmin(BaseUserAdmin):
    inlines = (lab_user_inline, )

admin.site.unregister(User)
admin.site.register(User, UserAdmin)
```

I can see the new fields in "Authentication and Authorization", which I guess means I've done everything "right".

When I try to call fields in a template using `{{ request.user.x }}` where `x` could be `first_name`, `personal_order_list_url` or `abbreviation_code`, I can retrieve the desired value for `first_name` and `personal_order_list_url`, but not for `abbreviation_code`.

If `request.user.personal_order_list_url` works, `request.user.abbreviation_code` should work too, shouldn't it?

Comment: Are you sure `request.user.personal_order_list_url` works? `User` doesn't have that property. You should access it with `request.user.lab_user.personal_order_list_url`.

Comment: Your code would be more readable if you used the standard convention for naming classes. `LabUser` and `LabUserInline`. It even looks better with the code highlighting on SO. https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#class-names

Comment: Good suggestions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

request.user.lab_user.personal_order_list_url